# Your PC/Device needs to be repaired (external hard drive plugged in during boot). Error code 0xc000000e

Tags: boot, windows-10, external-hard-drive

Sometimes when I boot my Windows 10 computer I get a bluescreen with error code 0xc000000e saying "Your PC/Device needs to be repaired". Recently I realized that this happens when I've my external hard drive plugged in and turned on. Why does this produce such an error? Shouldn't it be okay to have a hard drive connected on startup? What can I do to prevent it (except not booting with hard drive plugged in)?

Comment: You will need to use windbg and analyse the .dmp file that is generated to determine the cause.

Answer (score 2):

BSoD error 0xC000000E stands for the following error:

```
0xC000000E - The system has failed to start because a required device is inaccessible.
```

The reason for this error to occur can be due to several reasons.

1. The external harddrive is malfunctioning
2. With the external harddrive attached, a driveletter is assigned that causes your normal harddrive letter to change. Windows tries to load files from your normal harddrive but ends up trying to access non-existing files from your external drive.
3. You have not set your boot-order correct and it is attempting to boot from your external harddrive.

It is impossible to solve your problem with the limited information you have provided, so explaining the error itself is the best we can do here on SuperUser. It will be up to you to figure out why it happens.